# Index was out of range issue with gridview and its binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, gridview

I have a grid with 500+ records. On the very first page, when I randomly select any item and clicks on edit it will work, but after paging to any page it gives me exception

```
> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection. Parameter name: index
```

I have cross checked : Viewstate is enabled, grid is binding properly.

Below are my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a comman separated value of the id selected in the grid.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="gv"></param>
/// <param name="checkbox"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string GetGridViewsSelectedRowValues(GridView gv, string checkbox)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if(gv.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            var cbx = (CheckBox) row.FindControl(checkbox);
            if(cbx!=null && cbx.Checked)
            {
                var dataKey = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
                if (dataKey != null) sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", dataKey.Value));
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString().Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(','));
}
```

My Edit Button clicked event:

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = Common.GridSelectedRows(gvCityMaster, "chkBxSelect");
    if (count > 1)
    {
        Common.ShowMessage("Only one item can be edited at once.");
    }
    else
    {
        int id = Common.ParseInt(Common.GetGridViewsSelectedRowValues(gvCityMaster, "chkBxSelect"));
        if (id > 0)
        {
            DisplayForm();
            DisplayUserDetails(id);
        }
    }
}
```

I even looked into the DataKeys Collection, its coming 18 in each collection, which is fine.

Comment: With paging `GridView.Rows` does only return the current page, not all pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView.Rows` only returns all rows of the current page. You can use `ViewState` to store your comma separated values of ID's in the GridView.

```
private string SelectedIDs{
    get {
        if (ViewState("SelectedIDs") == null {
            ViewState("SelectedIDs") = "";
        }
        return (String)ViewState("SelectedIDs");
    }
    set { ViewState("SelectedIDs") = value; }
}
```

You need to update the string in `PageIndexChanging`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. AFAICU above piece of code is for maintaining the state of selected checkboxes while paging.. but what I need is that, after paging to some page, when i select a check box and click on delete, the above mentioned code, gives error...

Comment: Or simply i can say after paging the if(cbx!=null && cbx.Checked)
            {
                var dataKey = gv.DataKeys[row.RowIndex];
               ` if (dataKey != null) sb.Append(string.Format("{0},", dataKey.Value));
            }` stops working

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didn't work for me (using C# .Net 4.5) when paging, so I came up with another solution.

Note: I made the row editable on selection rather than a button (first function).

```
protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gridView.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            row.Attributes["onclick"] = ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(gridView, "Select$" + row.DataItemIndex, true);
        }
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}

protected void trackingDataGV_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    getGridViewData();
}

protected void gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        int pageSize = gridView.PageSize;
        int pageIndex = gridView.PageIndex;
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        int newRowIndex = 0;

        if (pageIndex > 0)
        {
            newRowIndex = pageIndex * pageSize;
            rowIndex = rowIndex - newRowIndex;
        }

    string valueXYZ = ((HiddenField)gridView.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("valueXYZ")).Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a checkbox inside a template field:

```
<asp:GridView ID="EditListGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="3" >
    <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="Include" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Checkbox_Click"  AutoPostBack="true"  />
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

To get the total index, use:

```
int i = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent).DataItemIndex;
```

To get the index on the current page, use:

```
int i = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent).RowIndex;
```

To get the checkbox in a paged gridview (use index on the current page):

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)EditListGridView.Rows[i].FindControl("Include");
```